# unexpected url changes when post request done

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

I am writing a simple web service and on the web UI (the url is "localhost:9001") there is a button that triggers function `indexIt`, which raise a POST request and the server respond with json.

```
<button type="submit" id="indexButton" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="indexIt()">Index</button>
```

The relevant code is:

```
function displayResponse(msg) {
    var shown = JSON.stringify(msg, null, 2);
    $(hintTextSelector).text(shown);
}

function indexDoneHint(response) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
    displayResponse(response);
}

function getLOptions() {
    return {
        "stem": $("#cb-index-stem").is(":checked"),
        "ignore": $("#cb-index-ignore").is(":checked"),
        "swDict": $("#lb-index-stopwords").val()
    }
}

function indexIt() {
    var indexOptions = getLOptions();
    var privateParam = {
        "method": "POST",
        "url": _getUrl("indexDoc"),
        "data": JSON.stringify(indexOptions)
    };
    $.extend(privateParam, commonParam);
    $.ajax(privateParam).done(indexDoneHint).error(onError);
}
```

The problem is that when I trigger the request by pressing the button, the url would change to "localhost:9001/?" (trailing `/?`) was added.

Strangely when I'm using the developer console and invoke `indexIt()`, the page remains "localhost:9001"

Comment: show us the code of indexit() frunction

Comment: when you use type="submit" it will submit your page . so if you dont want to submit it then use AJAx call and make button as type='button' instead of submit.

Comment: @BhawinParkeria just added the code.

Comment: @bharatpatel i think you're right. sorry could you explain it a bit more? i'm a newbie to html:-(

Comment: @BhawinParkeria following bharatpatel's suggestion i made it.

Comment: where is _getUrl() function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use button`<button>` in your form then on click it automatically submit form.
instead of button tag use input tag i.e 
`<input type="button" id="indexButton" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="indexIt()" value="Index It"  />`

OR use return keyword

1. `<button type="submit" id="indexButton" class="btn btn-primary"
   onclick="return indexIt()" >Index</button>`
2. in your javascript function "indexIt()" at the end use "return false" so it will run your js code and stop execution.

```js
    function indexIt() {
    var indexOptions = getLOptions();
    var privateParam = {
        "method": "POST",
        "url": _getUrl("indexDoc"),
        "data": JSON.stringify(indexOptions)
    };
    $.extend(privateParam, commonParam);
    $.ajax(privateParam).done(indexDoneHint).error(onError);
    
   return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just make button as simple button instead of submit button, type="button"

```
<button type="button" id="indexButton" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="indexIt()">Index</button>
```

OR

```
<input type="button" id="indexButton" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="indexIt()">Index</button>
```

Because when you make button as submit it will submit your page to action written in Form tag.